# 'cannot open shared object file' with OpenOnload

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, ping, sudo, openonload

I have built and installed https://github.com/Xilinx-CNS/onload shared lib.

Then I am trying:
`onload ping 8.8.8.8`

Got this error:

```
    ERROR: ld.so: object 'libonload.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored. 
    PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data. 64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=110 time=29.2 ms
```

But it works with `sudo onload ping 8.8.8.8`:

```
    oo:ping[724989]: netif_tcp_helper_alloc_u: ENODEV. This error can occur if:
     - no Solarflare network interfaces are active/UP, or they are running    packed stream firmware or are disabled, and
     - there are no AF_XDP interfaces registered with sfc_resource Please check your configuration.
     PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data. 64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=110 time=50.4 ms
```

Can someone help me, how I can achieve this command working without sudo? For example, `onload nc -l $PORT` works without sudo, but ping do not.

Some debug information:

`sudo find / -name libonload.so`:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libonload.so
```

`cat /etc/ld.so.conf`

```
include /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf
```

`cat /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf`

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfakeroot 
/usr/local/lib 
/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu 
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu  
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu 
/lib32  
/usr/lib32
```

`sudo ldconfig -v`:

```
... 
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfakeroot:  
    libfakeroot-0.so -> libfakeroot-tcp.so 
/usr/local/lib: 
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:
    ...
    libonload_ext.so.2 -> libonload_ext.so.2.0.0 
    libonload.so -> libonload.so
    ...
...
```

`ls -l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu | grep onload`

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   9528312 Mar  3 01:17 libonload.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    106222 Mar  3 01:17 libonload_ext.a 
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root        18 Mar  3 01:17 libonload_ext.so -> libonload_ext.so.2 
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root        22 Mar  3 01:17 libonload_ext.so.2 -> libonload_ext.so.2.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root     31344 Mar  3 01:17 libonload_ext.so.2.0.0
```

`ls -l /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu | grep onload`

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   9528312 Mar  3 01:17 libonload.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    106222 Mar  3 01:17 libonload_ext.a 
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root        18 Mar  3 01:17 libonload_ext.so -> libonload_ext.so.2
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root        22 Mar  3 01:17 libonload_ext.so.2 -> libonload_ext.so.2.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root     31344 Mar  3 01:17 libonload_ext.so.2.0.0
```

`/lib$ ls -l | grep x86_64-linux-gnu`

```
drwxr-xr-x 35 root root  36864 Mar  3 01:17 x86_64-linux-gnu
```

`/usr/lib$ ls -l | grep x86_64-linux-gnu`

```
drwxr-xr-x 35 root root  36864 Mar  3 01:17 x86_64-linux-gnu
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely reason is the `ping` application uses `setuid` but the Onload library isn't installed with that. Running `ping` will effectively promote the application to root user to allow the creation of a raw socket but the library will be loaded as the regular user and so it can't be used. Running as the root user avoids this since the library is loaded as the root user to start with.

I don't think GitHub version of Onload supports loading with `setuid` for the Onload library but you can set this yourself using `chmod +s <libpath>`. It's worth pointing out that `ping` isn't accelerated by Onload since the library will only accelerate UDP and TCP socket and pipes so you wouldn't see any benefit from this.